# is_dir not working with codeginiter on windows platform

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory, file-exists

I have an array in a CI controller like below

```
Array
        (
            [user_id] => 109676506743696803215
            [sub_dirs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [legacyListID] => 00984bc3-aaa3-4519-be03-09a73623f2b1
                            [slug] => st-peters-model-school
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [legacyListID] => 092452b5-3bc1-4f8e-96d4-dfb96e3af9fc
                            [slug] => sri-aurobindo-international-school
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [legacyListID] => 0d65157d-9bf6-44e9-9b72-ab9e37faa130
                            [slug] => suprabhat-model-high-school
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [legacyListID] => 20358e6f-7b15-4efb-b259-e4a34fea37ad
                            [slug] => rushi-high-school
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [legacyListID] => 262c1151-d39c-4ae4-b9c9-f68fa606fda3
                            [slug] => vignan-high-school
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [legacyListID] => 5d064b73-97f0-43b6-8aa6-da98cbca646e
                            [slug] => smart-kidz-play-school
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [legacyListID] => 68015e74-bba8-460a-93f7-282c3bf7ddb8
                            [slug] => gurukila-vidyapeeth-high-school
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [legacyListID] => 76ff39b9-e9a4-4b2b-bc8b-36e11089e3e7
                            [slug] => the-mothers-integral-school
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [legacyListID] => a31c7919-2007-4f83-8674-57010c43520f
                            [slug] => sr-digi-school
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [legacyListID] => cf078592-d7ce-46f6-b18c-8c6ead70f1d8
                            [slug] => gautami-talent-school
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [legacyListID] => eccebdea-8db9-4f45-8016-235a6a03ff6f
                            [slug] => anglist-high-school
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [legacyListID] => fdc44658-bed0-458e-85b0-6897d1175a93
                            [slug] => pratibha-high-school
                        )

                )
```

Here user_id is a folder name and i have sub_dirs inside the folder. sub_dirs variable has array of data with actual sub dir names in user_id folder and a rename parameter (slug) to rename it.

I am doing like below

```
foreach ($dirs as $dir) {

    $dirPath='images/profile/'.$dir['user_id'];

    if(is_dir($dirPath)){

        foreach ($dir['sub_dirs'] as $sub) {

            $subDir=$dirPath."/".$sub['legacyListID'];

            if(is_dir($subDir)){
                rename($subDir,$sub['slug']);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My Operating system is Windows. can you help me if i am missing something like permission issues or any helpers to do so in codeigniter.

FYI: The **images/profiles/(dir)/(subDir)** is in root folder

Comment: is it failing for all the subdirs, or just some?

Comment: it is failing at first if condition itself i.e. directory path

Comment: Just wanted to check, is the root folder the webroot or the drive root?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your images folder is inside the application path you should use`APPPATH` CI variable:

```
FCPATH   -> '/'
BASEPATH -> '/system/'
APPPATH  -> '/application/'
```

Comment: it is in root folder tried with FCPATH No luck though

Answer (score 0):

Use FCPATH for directory location

```
foreach ($dirs as $dir) {

    $dirPath = FCPATH . 'images/profile/'. $dir['user_id'];

    if(is_dir($dirPath)){

        foreach ($dir['sub_dirs'] as $sub) {

            $subDir = $dirPath ."/". $sub['legacyListID'];

            if(is_dir($subDir)){
                rename($subDir, $sub['slug']);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Make sure though your images folder is located in the main directory

```
application

images >

images > profile
```

You could also use `dirname(FCPATH) . '/images/profile/'. $dir['user_id'];`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using `scandir` Function in PHP like below

```
foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
       $path="images/profiles";

       $curDir=$path."/".$dir['user_id'];

           if(is_dir($curDir)){

            foreach ($dir['sub_dirs'] as $i => $sub) {

                foreach (scandir($curDir) as $subDir) {

                    if($subDir == $sub['legacyListID']){

                        $old=$curDir."/".$sub['legacyListID'];
                        $rename=$curDir."/".$sub['slug'];

                        rename($old, $rename);
                    }

                }
            }

           }
        }
```

Basically dirs is the actual array which has all dirs and subdirs and renaming arrays in it.

SO i scanned the each dir and got all the sub dirs, so whenever there is a match i changed named.

understood rename wont work good with for loop. we have first get all get sub dirs in a directory and match with your own array then rename it.

ALL GOOD :)